# JSON.NET JObject.Load() disconnected JSON

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

In a library, I have a method that accept a JObject as parameter.
I would like to keep this JObject instance for later use, but i dont know it's lifetime.

if it was created by `JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(jsonFile));` then i am all ok, the entire JSON is in memory **and wont be disposed until `JObject` is destroyed**..

but if it was created from a JsonTextReader **using `JObject.Load()`** ...
My question is What happen if the stream is closed ?
Does the JObject still working fine, or is it invalid ?

**I sandboxed a check and it seems to be working even after the FileStream is disposed, but i am not sure it is "Bullet proof" for lets say a bigger JSON file, or deeply nested.**

if it is invalid, how can I tell JSON.NET to create a "in-memory" JObject from it ?

**Edits in bold**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I sandboxed a check and it seems to be working even after the FileStream is disposed, but i am not sure it is "Bullet proof" for lets say a bigger JSON file, or deeply nested.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the JObject was created from a string or from a stream; the JObject will still remain in memory until you let it fall out of scope.  Closing the original stream does not make the JObject lose its data.

Comment: @BrianRogers do you have any reference of that? because it seems like it, but i dont know if i can be positively sure.

Comment: The best reference is looking at the source code itself.  See my answer.

Comment: After deserialization there is no connection between the resulting `JObject` and data source whatever it is. `JObject.Load` creates an instance of the `JObject` with data filled and the lifetime for this instance depends on GC and how it is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the `JObject` was created from a string or from a stream; the `JObject` and the data it holds will still remain in memory until you let the `JObject` fall out of scope. Closing the original stream does not make the `JObject` lose its data.

If you're not convinced from your own sandbox testing, the best proof you'll find is examining the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) itself.  If you take a look at the [`JObject`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs) class and its base class, [`JToken`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs) you can see that while they have methods to read data from a `JsonReader`, they do not hold onto a reference to the reader outside of those methods.  Neither class has any references to `Streams`.

Conversely, the [`JsonReader`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonReader.cs) and [`JsonTextReader`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs) classes do not have any references to `JToken` or `JObject` at all.  If you look at the [`JsonReaderInternalSerializer`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs) class you can see that it has methods to create `JTokens` and `JObjects`, but in doing so it uses a [`JTokenWriter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JTokenWriter.cs) to copy the data into those objects.  There isn't any permanent link between them.

Dig as deep as you need to convince yourself.  If you're still not convinced, then download the source code and step through it with a debugger.

Comment: thanks, didn't think about looking at the actual code, that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading all the text at once [`File.ReadAllText(jsonFile)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8)

> Opens a text file, reads all the text in the file into a string, and
>   then closes the file.

Once the data (in your case an allocated string in memory) is parsed using the ([`JObject.Parse`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) method) the `JObject` is additionally `allocated` and stays in *memory* backed by the data you gave it (until it falls out of *scope*).

If you edit it, or do anything else, it doesn't edit the original source.

It's as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks, though my question was on using `JObject.Load(StreamReader)`, if that persist after the StreamReader goes off scope, but the JObject lives. (my issue is that i dont control how is the JObject created, i just get a reference and worry if i should keep it after the method finish.

Comment: @TomerW once the you call load, the stream has been read as far as it can be read, JObject doesn't keep a reference to the reader, it just reads from it in load, if it falls out of scope and gets garbage collected nothing bad can happen.